# Numerical strategy to calculate a fraction sometimes very close to zero

Tags: r, numerical-stability, numerical-computing

In the R function `chisq.test()` there is the following line:

`PVAL <- (1 + sum(ss >= almost.1 * STATISTIC))/(B + 1)` with

`almost.1 <- 1 - 64 * .Machine$double.eps`

This is clearly a computational adjustment to avoid getting round outputs for `PVAL.`

It doesn't really matter what is calculated, but the idea is that what we really, really want is `sum(ss >= STATISTIC)/ B`, where `ss` is the result of a bunch of simulations, `STATISTIC` is a fixed value to compare to, and `B` is the number of simulations. We are calculating the percentage of cases in which `ss` is greater than `STATISTIC.`

What does adding `1` to both numerator and denominator supposed to accomplish?

and

Why do we need to multiply by `1 - 64 * .Machine$double.eps`?